# Laravel not picking up the correct route

Tags: laravel

I am developing an application using Laravel 8.x. I have an api.php file that I am using. It was all working fine for the last 5 months. Today I added a new route to the api.php file and that route is not getting picked up by the Laravel. I have the following items in the api.php file

[image]

```
//Products
Route::get('/products/{currency_id?}/{type?}/{eventtype?}', [Controllers\ProductsController::class, 'getproduct2']);
Route::get('/products/search/{query}/{itemtype?}/{itemcategory?}', [Controllers\ProductsController::class, 'findproduct']); //getproduct
Route::post('/products/findproductbyid/{product_id}', [Controllers\ProductsController::class, 'getproduct']);
Route::post('/products/create', [Controllers\ProductsController::class, 'setproduct']);
Route::post('/products/update', [Controllers\ProductsController::class, 'putproduct']);
```

And it shows up the URL list also

[image]

but when I access it (findproductbyid) in the browser it is not getting picked up. it shows the results of /products/{currency_id}/{type}/{eventtype}

Please tell me to know why is it so? I tried clearing Laravel cache, etc.

Thanks in advance

UPDATE: I tried changing the GET to POST, but it seems it is not getting updated to POST

[image]

Comment: When asking questions on stackoverflow please include code and not images of code.

Comment: Let's try to move the route `/products/findproductbyid/{product_id}` above the route `/products/{currency_id}/{type}/{eventtype}`

Comment: Tried doing that. It looks like laravel is not picking up changes made that particluar method or the change is not getting reflected. I added a new update method[POST] and that one got picked up. @Locoho

Comment: is there a way i can use a different file other than api.php to store my api's

Comment: Are your routes cached?

Comment: @logeeks your problem is the conflict of route path, I think you need to change your path to more flexible to work with, like: `/products/{productId}` to get the product by id, `/products` to searching by passing query params to route and handle it in the controller, example `/products?currency_id=1&type=A&....`

Answer (score 2):

You don't define url parameters with `$`, here you done {$product_id}

Change it to the following.

```
Route::get('/products/findbyproductid/{product_id}', [...]);
```

Comment: Thanks, changed that.  but the problem persists

Comment: updated the code in the question as well. Thanks

Comment: Does your php artisan route:list show the same?

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange the routes like this and try it out

```php
Route::post('/products/findproductbyid/{product_id}', [Controllers\ProductsController::class, 'getproduct']);
Route::get('/products/search/{query}/{itemtype?}/{itemcategory?}', [Controllers\ProductsController::class, 'findproduct']); //getproduct
Route::get('/products/{currency_id?}/{type?}/{eventtype?}', [Controllers\ProductsController::class, 'getproduct2']);
```

Comment: Tried that . the laravel is not picking up changes on that method

Comment: Your routes are messy, that is not Laravels fault, please update your route list and let's see whats going on

Comment: @logeeks What does it say when you try to call the route